# Issue with the phsical query in managesessions & nqquery log file?

Tags: obiee

[image]

Hi,

This is on practitioner level of question demo in obiee,
I ran an analysis with administrator user,If i go and check the physical query in administration--> manage session & in nqquery log file,It is showing this picture which i have attached.As I set my loglevel=2 in 
biadmintool. Also i set loglevel=7 it doesn't work
Please help me out,I can't understand what is an issue,
Advance thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are querying XML files from the SampleApp.

The log is perfectly correct and with XML files you will never see a "physical query" sent against them as they are files and not a data source like a database (SQL) or a cube (MDX).

Comment: Hi chris, Thank you for your answer.So, I need to import the metadata from datasource in physical layer right? DB with connection pool.

Comment: It all depends: What do you want to do? You do not state what your target is.SampleApp Lite is a demo schema based on XML files.

Comment: I want to import metadata from db to physical layer as I understood now the above is the XML file,it's done with your help.Thank you.